# External monitor doesn't switch on automatically when laptop wakes up from sleep

Tags: laptop, display, sleep

I've an external monitor connected to my laptop, and work primary on that external monitor (with laptop monitor off). Recently I found that, as I open the laptop lid to wake up the machine, the laptop monitor fires up instead of the external. This only starts to occur recently, and I believe the only thing I did these few days was to install AMD Catalyst Control Center, and changed a bit of resolution setting (nothing else) on the external.

Restarting the machine does not cause this problem (i.e. it remembers which monitor it is supposed to use upon restart). Is there anything I can do to ensure it's the external monitor that gets activated when the computer wakes up?

My computer is [more or less this model](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834131393), and [this is my monitor](http://www8.hp.com/ca/en/products/monitors/product-detail.html?oid=5173335). Thanks!

**EDIT**: Somehow I get it fixed by allowing Windows to search for the "latest" driver for my graphics card, which happens to be older than the current one. I presume this was altered during the installation of AMD CCC.

Comment: installing the new drivers may have changed your power options - If you click Start and type "change what closing the lid does". You may have to mess with the settings in here in order to adjust said action

Comment: The settings are all "sleep" there - same as before.
http://i.imgur.com/PqGcMn6.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like with the latest drivers, the settings are not saved when coming from sleep. But retained for restart. If you updated AMD drivers recently, this could be a bug. Reverting to older driver should help solve your issue.

Comment: This is indeed what I did.. I eventually removed the Catalyst Center or otherwise some games won't even run. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be happening after installing the drivers just install the your monitor drivers from the official site it will solve your problem, And it will also gives you optimal picture quality.